# Oracle SQL Joining three Tables and sorting by Highest Values

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, join, window-functions

I have the following three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(customerID     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
customerZip     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN     VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
vehicleModel        VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE SALES
(saleID         INT     PRIMARY KEY,
customerID      INT,
vehicleVIN      VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(customerID),
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (vehicleVIN) REFERENCES VEHICLES(vehicleVIN));
```

I'm trying to develop a query to join these three tables and produce an output that displays the total count of sales by model and the total count of sales by zip code, sorted by the highest values first. The output should look similar to this:

```
vehicleModel    Sales_By_Model    customerZip   Sales_By_ZIP
        S-10                12          18956              3
   Silverado                10          22789              2
       F-150                 9          12345              2
```

I've tried the following code, but I don't believe it is the correct approach to take this bull by the horns because it does not combine the vehicleModel for a total count of Sales_By_Model:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.vehicleModel, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.vehicleVIN) "SALES_BY_MODEL", c.customerZip, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customerZip )"SALES_BY_ZIP" 
FROM SALES s, VEHICLES v, CUSTOMERS c
WHERE s. vehicleVIN = v. vehicleVIN
and  c. customerID = s. customerID    
ORDER BY 2 DESC , 4 DESC;
```

This is the output that I get from the query I've worked above:

```
VEHICLEMODEL    SALES_BY_MODEL CUSTOMERZIP     SALES_BY_ZIP
accord                       1 89523                      6
altima                       1 89523                      6
escalade                     1 89523                      6
f-150                        1 89523                      6
impala                       1 89523                      6
```

Although the query does pull the necessary data and joins the tables, it doesn't combine the vehicleModel(s) to increase the count for SALES_BY_MODEL. The same is happening with the customerZIP, although it does seem to be at least counting the zip's correctly.

My question is: is there a way to query these tables for a result that combines the counts for both vehicleModel and customerZip? And if so, how should I do it? I know the query that I used above isn't exactly proper SQL syntax by explicitly calling the JOIN. My goal is to complete this in ONE SELECT Query.

Thank you in advance for your guidance/assistance!

EDIT: A few lines of sample input data are below:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
(customerID,customerFirName,customerLasName,customerMiName,customerStreet,customerState,customerCity,customerZip)
VALUES
(1,'Steven','Christman','J','11111 Address Way','Maryland','Hollywood','20636');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
(customerID,customerFirName,customerLasName,customerMiName,customerStreet,customerState,customerCity,customerZip)
VALUES
(2,'Bob','Seagram','A','22222 Seagram Lane','Texas','Houston','77001');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
(customerID,customerFirName,customerLasName,customerMiName,customerStreet,customerState,customerCity,customerZip)
VALUES
(3,'Sally','Anderson','P','33333 Pheonix Drive','Arizona','Pheonix','85001');

INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('147258HHE91K3RT','compact','chevrolet','spark','Maryland',20583.00,NULL);
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('789456ERT0923RFB6','Midsize','ford','Taurus','washington, d.c.',25897.22,1);
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('1234567890QWERTYUIOP','fullsize','Lincoln','towncar','Virginia',44222.10,NULL);

INSERT INTO SALES
(saleID,grossSalePrice,vehicleStatus,saleDate,saleMileage,customerID,salespersonID,vehicleVIN)
VALUES
(1,25987.28,'sold',date '2012-10-15',10,1,1,'147258HHE91K3RT');
INSERT INTO SALES
(saleID,grossSalePrice,vehicleStatus,saleDate,saleMileage,customerID,salespersonID,vehicleVIN)
VALUES
(2,29999.99,'sold',date '2012-10-17',50087,2,2,'789456ERT0923RFB6');
INSERT INTO SALES
(saleID,grossSalePrice,vehicleStatus,saleDate,saleMileage,customerID,salespersonID,vehicleVIN)
VALUES
(3,47490.88,'sold',date '2012-11-05',30,3,3,'1234567890QWERTYUIOP');
```

As you may notice, the input data above reflects input to some other attributes that I did not list in the original post (where I displayed the table creations) since most of these attributes are non-relational to the goal here.

Comment: You seem to be trying to combine two completely separate queries into one, which isn't sensible.  What if there are only 5 models of vehicle but 9 customer zip codes, what should your report look like then? Just write two queries and display them side by side if required.

Comment: It would be really helpful to have example input data that corresponds to example output results.  Because, as @TonyAndrews points out, trying to combine these two metrics feels "awkward" at the very least.  Are you trying to show "Every combination of Model and Zip", then next to those dimensions to include metrics for "How many of that Model was sold, regardless of Zip" as well as "How many were sold in that Zip, regardless of model", but not actually have any metric specific to the Model/Zip on any given row?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm doing this based off instruction that I have been provided. The customerZIP and vehicleMake don't have to be "linked" meaning that the vehicleMake attribute "S-10" doesn't necessarily have to be purchased by a customer in customerZip attribute "18956." 

The specific instruction that I've been provided is to "Display the total count of sales, by model and then by zip code, with the highest values first via a single select query. This given, I don't believe they HAVE to be side by side. It's just what I thought would be the easier means of display.

Comment: So, in your example, the 12 sales of `S-10` have ***nothing*** to do with the 3 sales in Zip `18956`???  Even though they're on the same row of the same data set?

Comment: @MatBailie It doesn't need to show the combination of model and zip. Imagine it as two separate lists that are side-by-side. One Shows a list of models and sales by model, and another shows a list of zip codes and sales by zip code. The two do not need to be tied together, other than the fact that they need to be displayed via the same query. Adding input data now. Thanks!

Comment: ***Do Not Do This In SQL***.  As I understand your requirement, you have two queries that should be written separately, and executed separately *(potentially even concurrently)*.  Your ***presentation layer*** may then do all sort of things to that data to present it in what ever format you like; be that as a single table or ***preferably*** as two tables sat next to each other.  But SQL is exactly the wrong place for that kind of work.  It will lead to no end of difficulty in the future.  ***Do not do this...***

Comment: @MatBailie, Thanks for the guidance. I will note that for the future. For now, I'm just trying to do what I've been asked...

Comment: Part of being a competent developer is being able to challenge overly specific requirements and return with better solutions that identify and fulfill the actual functional requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example way to achieve this shows that you're actually running two independent queries, and just pretending that they're related.

Doing so then increases the execution cost, reduces the ability to test and/or maintain, prevents code-reuse and generally breaches every relevant software engineering principle I can think of.

So, here's how do a very bad thing...

```
WITH
  ranked_model_sales AS
(
  SELECT
    vehicles.vehicleModel,
    COUNT(*)                                     AS total_model_sales,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)   AS rank_id
  FROM
    sales
  INNER JOIN
    vehicles
      ON sales.vehicleVIN = vehicles.vehicleVIN
  GROUP BY
    vehicles.vehicleModel
),
  ranked_zip_sales AS
(
  SELECT
    customers.customerZip,
    COUNT(*)                                     AS total_zip_sales,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)   AS rank_id
  FROM
    sales
  INNER JOIN
    customers
      ON sales.customerID= customers.customerID
  GROUP BY
    customers.customerZip
)
SELECT
  m.vehicleModel,
  m.total_model_sales,
  z.customerZip,
  z.total_zip_sales
FROM
  ranked_model_sales    m
FULL OUTER JOIN
  ranked_zip_sales      z
    ON m.rank_id = z.rank_id
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(m.rank_id, z.rank_id)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try, however I think I'm going to heed your warning and try this the correct way. I'm really trying to learn SQL in-depth and correctly, and will do what I have to do to satisfy a direct requirement, however will certainly argue the fact of correctness with those who instruct me to "break the rules" so to speak. I appreciate you taking the time to clearly and thoroughly explain this to me.

Comment: so either this didn't work, or I'm implementing it way incorrectly. I copied and pasted your code above to give it a shot, and I get no output. No errors, but nothing outputs. Is there a specific place or way I should be implementing this? Thanks.

Comment: @SteveC - Then you're doing something wrong, there is a typo in there that should give you an error message.  (`toal_zip_sales`) Here's a demo I wrote on the train using my phone, add whatever data you like.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1915de/2

Comment: @MatBaile - Sorry, forgot to update you again last night. I figured it out. I was just forgetting to end the ORDER BY Statement with a ";" Sorry about that. Your answer works. Thank you!!